# Error in pyautogui

Tags: python-2.7, pygui

I use Python 2.7 on a windows 7. I use pycharm and IDLE. I was trying out pyautogui for some automatic mouse movements, but the program returned that puautogui as not defined. I have read online that pyautogui doesnot require any additional packages in windows.

I typed import pyautogui in IDLE and it turned up an error. Can u help ?

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit          (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import pyautogui

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
import pyautogui
ImportError: No module named pyautogui
>>>
```

Comment: Just to be clear: it sounds like you did not install pyautogui... if that's not true, how did you install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install PyAutoGUI, install the pyautogui package from PyPI and dependencies.

On Windows for Python 2.7, this is:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe -m pip install pyautogui
```

Comment: Great. I just needed to install pyautogui and then it worked.

Answer (score -1):

it is saing that pyautogui couldn't be found b y the interpreter... are you sure you installed it....

if no.....
first type
pip uninstall PyautoGUI and then
please  type  pip install PyautoGUI in CMD or Powershell

for more information go to :
https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/